# How to control a javascript function to run if an element is not clicked and stop if an element is clicked

Tags: javascript

I have a page that contains a div that refreshes every 3 seconds that looks like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
      $("#here").load(window.location.href + " #here" );
}, 3000);
});
</script>

<div id="here">
/* Div content, contains an html table*/
</div>
```

I want the refresh script to stop if a certain <td> in the HTML table is clicked. When the user clicks outside of the cell, I want the refresh script to continue running.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: use clearInterval

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  What have you tried?  Please edit your question and add in the code segment that demonstrates your best attempt at resolving this, and then explain at what point in your code you aren't getting the results you expect.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a `start()` function

   - Use `setInterval` to start the counter, remember it's returned `pid`
2. Define a `end()` function

   - Use `clearInterval` on the `pid` to stop the counter
3. Define a eventListener on all the `tr`'s that will call the `stop()` function
4. Define a eventListener on `document` that will call `start()` if we're not already counting (`!pid`) and we didn't click on a `<tr>` or `<th>`:
   `![ 'TD', 'TH' ].includes(e.target.nodeName)`

```js
let pid = null;

const start  = () => {
    console.log('Starting interval action');
    pid = setInterval(() => {
        console.log('setInterval Action')
    }, 3000);
}
const stop  = () => {
    console.log('Stopping interval action');
    clearInterval(pid);
    pid = null;
}

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (![ 'TD', 'TH' ].includes(e.target.nodeName) && !pid) {
        start();
    }
});
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr')).forEach(e => {
    e.addEventListener('click', () => {
        stop();
    })
});
start();
```

```html
<div id="here">
  <table style='border: 1px solid black;'>
    <tr>
      <th>Key</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a variable name to `setInterval` function and make that variable global. Then, set an `onclick` event in your `<td>` which will clear the `setInterval`. For example:

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var refresh = setInterval(function () {
      $("#here").load(window.location.href + " #here");
    }, 3000);
  });
</script>

<td onclick="clearInterval(refresh)"></td>
```

Here, as name suggests, `clearInterval` function clears **Interval** which was gave it to.

[See more](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) at W3Schools' website.